# Considering dropping Computer Science Master

Tags: masters, computer-science

Background knowledge about me: I'm 26, have done a Bachelors in Mathematics and now I'm in my 3rd year in my masters in Computer Science in Germany.

I have found it very difficult in general to decide what to study, I've always been into learning things without specifying a passion and I've been a very good student. When I started my Bachelors in Math I really struggled because it was very theoretical but during the first year I decided that I would go into Applied Math and Computer Science.

Starting my Masters the courses were difficult and again I couldn't decide where to focus so I went with Machine Learning, since it was closer to my previous studies. Although I've finished all my courses I am really struggling with my Master Project(which is in Machine Learning), it doesn't seem interesting to me so I am just procrastinating. I decided not to change the project and try to find something else, because I thought that all of this time I have spend would be wasted.

I'm considering dropping the master and searching for a job, but that's also a problem since I don't have any experience.

Since it has taken me some time to finish my Bachelors and now I am really strugling with my Masters, should I leave it and try to acquire some knowledge from online courses about things that would be more relevant for a job?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia.SE! Can you [edit] your post to clarify your specific question? (See ["Here's my situation, any suggestions?" is not an answerable question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1205/11365))

Comment: Only you can decide whether you should quit your degree. If you do, then it seems unnecessary "to acquire some knowledge from online courses about things that would be more relevant for a job," because employers hire graduates without additional courses.

Comment: What's the dream goal? If you're not interested in doing computer science research with machine learning, the MS is not going to help you. If you're interested in writing code, the Master's might look nice but if it's a background in machine learning that may not help you either.

Answer (score 1):

Get that football across the goal line.  Your project is pass fail.  Just finish it.  Don't change topics.

DON'T drop out after so much time spent. After all, all the same options for career redirect will be there even if you have that extra sheepskin in your pocket.

P.s.  I hear you on the procrastination and avoidance.  but you have to find something to spur you on.  For me it was publishing.  Got a lot of egoboo from that.  Then the thesis was a cut and paste.  Maybe that works for you (can even sign up for a conference to push you).  But whatever the "trick" (e.g. "accountability buddy"), figure out something to push yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found it very difficult in general to decide what to study, I've always been into learning things without specifying a passion and I've been a very good student.

*Warning: I'm going to propose a very subjective answer, my interpretation might be completely wrong.*

My impression is that you are a perfectionist person and you get easily disappointed with the reality of... well everything: your courses, your level, your project topic... Nothing seems good enough for your high expectations. Being perfectionist can be a valuable quality but we don't live in a perfect world, you need to start accepting that.

What strikes me in your question is that you don't mention any personal preference: do you like maths? do you like CS, or ML? Are you eager to get a job or feel like studying longer? I'd suggest you need to find where your motivation lies in order to know what to do. I don't think anybody can answer your actual question except yourself, you are looking for advice about your own preferences.